# JSON to CSV: Parse error on line 1 - how to fix?

Tags: json, csv, eof

I am trying to convert a `.json` file to a `.csv` file; however, I am getting an error at line 1, which I am unsure how to solve.

Here are lines 1 to 5 of my `.json` :

```
{"text":"The morning is going so fast Part 2 of #DiscoveryDay is in full swing \ud83d\ude01\n\nGreat Atmosphere in the room \n\n#BIGSocial\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/P08qBoH6tv"}
{"text":"Double kill! #XiuKai lives! I died. \ud83d\ude0c https:\/\/t.co\/QCyk3r2JCb"}
{"text":"ALLTY \ud83d\udc94"}
{"text":"Shouldn\u2019t be normal for a 24 year old to be this tiered \ud83d\udca4"}
{"text":"@TheNames_BrieX Trust me! \ud83d\udcaf"}
```

This is the error that I am getting, which I am unsure how to fix:

```
Parse error on line 1:
.../t.co\/P08qBoH6tv"}{"text":"Double kill
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

Any help on how to solve this would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid, objects are not separated by a comma and you can't have multiple root elements

Here is one way to make your JSON fixed

```json
[
  {"text":"The morning is going so fast Part 2 of #DiscoveryDay is in full swing \ud83d\ude01\n\nGreat Atmosphere in the room \n\n#BIGSocial\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/P08qBoH6tv"},
  {"text":"Double kill! #XiuKai lives! I died. \ud83d\ude0c https:\/\/t.co\/QCyk3r2JCb"},
  {"text":"ALLTY \ud83d\udc94"},
  {"text":"Shouldn\u2019t be normal for a 24 year old to be this tiered \ud83d\udca4"},
  {"text":"@TheNames_BrieX Trust me! \ud83d\udcaf"}
]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I see that you have added a comma to fix the JSON. However, how would I add the commas if I have over 70,000 lines of this?

Comment: From where do you get your JSON file ? You have it generated from somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, generated from getting Twitter tweets that have emojis.

Comment: I don't know well the Twitter API but i doubt it returns invalid JSON. I do believe it returns one JSON object that you are appending to a file right ?

Comment: Well i don't know what programming language you are using to do this task, but you have multiple way to build a valid JSON file, like putting all your JSON objects results in an array then encode the array to json (thanks to a library or a function in your language) and store the output in a file; or output directly to your file and make sure that you will respect valid JSON requirements, in your case adding a comma at the end and not forgetting to add square brackets at the beginning and the end of your file

Comment: In the end you must have a valid JSON, otherwise any parser you can use won't likely be able to convert JSON to CSV

Comment: Right, I see - thanks for the help and helpful advice.